# Error in Postgresql Connection Port not connected

Tags: python, django, postgresql, environment-variables

I have started my ssh on local and I am trying to run python3 manage.py runserver but it gives this error?

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I also tried psql on terminal it gives me this error as well.

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I also check connection but it seems to be not working like

```
netstat -nltp | grep 5432
```

I tried to restart as well but still same error.

```
systemctl restart postgresql.service
```

I saw that after restarting the pg_lscluster gives me output as

```
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

But as soon as after few minutes its give me output as

```
12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

Here is the postgres log

[Postgresql Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H3V2.png)

Comment: Could you attach your `postgresql-12-main.log` please?

Comment: `netstat -nltp | grep 5432` will not help you if the client is trying to connect to a Unix domain socket.

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev I have edited the log if u can see in Link above

Comment: Something is regularly crashing your PostgreSQL database server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe what it could be, I am new born to this server side issue basically i can say on local its running but on server side which is production site is not working

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have mention my log file pic above in link "Postgresql Log"

Comment: Please don't post images of text... There are lots of "smart shutdown requests". You'll have to figure out who made them.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yeah i figure it out via deploy to newly created server for database only.